# What's the difference between the _T("...") and _RT("...") macros?

Tags: c++, string, macros

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't get the text searched for. If anyone can explain them, refer me to an article, or give me the correct search query I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Given that identifiers starting with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation, I'd discourage their use and guess your compiler manual is the place to look for an explanation.

Comment: @pmr: `_T(`) is _the_ standard Microsoft way to get wide/short char string literals depending on the UNICODE/DBCS compiler defines

Comment: Where did you find this "_RT" macro? I've not seen that one. Is that from WinRT or something?

Comment: Can you ask the compiler to show you the output of the preprocessor?

Comment: Are you working in a Windows environment? Are you using Visual Studio? If so you should be able to right-click the macros and select Go To Definition. Then you can see what the macros are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Apparently, the _RT macro is #define'd in our code. I used Jim Rhodes's suggestion, and it said the following: #define _RT(str) _T(str)...   (I still wonder what it's used for, as it seems pretty redundant to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a hunch but looking at the [Wikipedia C++11 Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals) for String Literals, and mixing it with what we know of the `_T` macro, it makes sense that the `_RT` macro could be about making `_T` based raw string literals.

You would have to take a look at the macro itself to see what it does. As the `_T` macro prepends `L` to the item if you're using unicode, my guess is that `_RT` would prepend `R` always and also `L` if Unicode.

So `_T` is used for dealing with normal string literals and making them unicode (`wchar_t`) or not, and `_RT` is used for making raw string literals and making them unicode or not.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense IMO

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `_RT()` (it seems [google agrees](http://tinyurl.com/63ruazh))

My first thought would "readonly" literal. Hmm that would be a bit redundant indeed, but IIRC the standard has become more strict with regards to const-ness of string literals in C++